# WordPress Modification. 2 Search Widgets, searching different content

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I modified the Searchform.php to:

```
 'search_id' => 'id', 'form_action' => ( 'http://local.amleo.com/newps/pulldata.php'
```

For the first Search widget, to go to a custom PHP page that displays results for something else.

The next Search Widget, I'd like to search the category "AML Hot Topics". Not sure how I can do that. Any ideas??

So you can visualize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFGBQ.png

The 1st Search is the one I modified the Searchform.php for. The 2nd is the one I'm not sure about.

I'm no super-duper PHP wizard by any means, but I can follow directions pretty decently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two target for search, instead you can do it using something like this

One form for `newps`

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="hidden" value="newps" name="key" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Search','Aggregate'); ?>" />
</form>
```

Another for `AML`

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="hidden" value="aml" name="key" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Search','Aggregate'); ?>" />
</form>
```

Create a `search.php` file in your theme's root folder, something like this

```
get_header();

// if you get `key` then it will be your custom search
// otherwise, default search will be performed
if(!empty($_GET['key'])) {
    $key = $_GET['key']; // it will be either 'newps' or 'aml'
    $search = $_GET['s'];
    // modify the query using your $key and $search param
    query_posts(...);
}

if (have_posts()) :
    while(have_posts()): the_post();
        // the_title() and more...
    endwhile;
endif;
// reset the query if modified
if(!empty($key)) wp_reset_query();

get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this form code. All I did on my site was include "Search" Widgets on the sidebar. Where do I put that code?? 

Also, the thing is, I have to pass the ID variable to newps, because the ID variable is used on that page.

Comment: You have two forms for two custom search, both forms are given above for those widgets.